# Format date of a Django variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery, django, date

I've got a **date** in the short format such as `Jan. 24 2019` as a **Django variable**.

How can I format this as `24/01/2019`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Django Template Filter:

```
{{ incoming_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}
```

Change `incoming_date` with your variable name.

To Learn More, [Go here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

---

#### Using Javascript

```js
var mydate = new Date('Jan. 24 2019');
var new_date = mydate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
console.log(new_date)
```

To Learn More, [Goto Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Using_locales)

Comment: I did but it said that it wouldn't be shown as I am pretty new to here.

Answer (score 0):

For date format in Django use `...,input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y',])`

Also in the place of HTML you can use `...,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })});</script>`